# Improving performance of switch from managed to unmanaged code

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged

I have built a C# wrapper for a commercial third-party DLL written in C++. What I've got works, but it does not perform as fast as expectations. The company that make the DLL also use it to power a piece of their own software: mine runs at about a sixth of the speed using the wrapper.

To improve performance I used a profiler to find the bottlenecks. This suggested that about 80% of the runtime was taken up in making calls direct to the third-party DLL. So, for example this function, which just returns an integer:

```
[DllImport("MyDllPath.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int QABatchWV_FormattedLineCount(int handle, ref int count);

private int LineCount(int searchHandle)
{
    int layoutLineCount = 0;
    int layoutLineCountReturn = QABatchWV_FormattedLineCount(searchHandle, ref layoutLineCount);

    return layoutLineCount;
}
```

Takes about 25% of the processing time. While this one:

```
[DllImport("MyDllPath.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int QABatchWV_Clean(int handle, StringBuilder searchString, ref int searchHandle, StringBuilder returnPostcode, int postcodeLength, StringBuilder isoCode, StringBuilder returnCode, int returnLength);

private int AddressClean(StringBuilder returnPostcode, StringBuilder countryISO, StringBuilder returnCode, StringBuilder inputAddress, out int searchHandle)
{
    searchHandle = 0;
    int searchResult = 0;
    searchResult = QABatchWV_Clean(ApiHandle, inputAddress, ref searchHandle, returnPostcode, 20, countryISO, returnCode, 256);

    return searchResult;
}
```

Takes about 35%.

The `handle` in the code suggests the dll has an initialisation overhead. However, I've tried to engineer my code to minimize this. My calling code sets up a batch of "pre-initalised" DLL threads, each with their own handle. It then uses these for the run before closing them all down. The DLL seems to have been built to pass handles around freely: so, you get a handle when you start a session, pass that down into a clean function to use that session to clean which in turns gives you "clean" handle which you then pass back to the DLL to get the line count and so on.

I'm new to working with unmanaged code and I'm at a loss as to what - if anything - I can do here. Are these sorts of bottlenecks an intrinsic cost of passing variables between managed and unmanaged code? Or are there any tricks I can employ to speed up the process?

Comment: what is `handle` - is there a connect/disconnect mechanism (does the third-party DLL do a lot of initialization on every call)?

Comment: @dlatikay Thanks for looking - see the edits. Hopefully that will explain stuff.

Comment: A bunch of things which may not make a difference: 1) force cdecl / stdcall 2) don't pass by reference, just return 3) make it `private static extern` 4) Lastly, can you paste your C++ code for the function? or a trimmed down version of it

Comment: I think you should reveal more of this algorithm. What do you expect to be a bottleneck? How many times does managed/unmanaged transition occur? If you suspect the problem is in transition, you might consider wrapping whole computation into C(++) DLL and provide final result of computation to .NET.

Comment: @crezefire Thanks for the suggestions - going to try some of them now. But I don't have the C++ code - it's third party, pre-compiled. All I have is the header file, describing the functions.